# Page scroll up when set data to redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When I set payload to redux/tookit state , My browser scroll to up !!

I was check out a redux state action so It does.

Why and how can I fix it?

I want to prevent additional scroll . (scroll to up)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: before you understand a problem , chatGPT solve my issues